# SVMModel.Beta and SVMModel.Bias are the 'coef_' and 'intercept_' respectively in scikit- learn?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, scikit-learn

I have a piece of code in MATLAB which I am supposed to code in python.  As I have no idea regarding MATLAB, can any please clarify, whether `SVMModel.Beta` and `SVMModel.Bias` are the `coef_` and `intercept_` respectively in scikit- learn?

```
function [euc_d]=EucledianDistance(x,w,b)
    euc_d=abs((sum(w.*x')+b))/sqrt(sum(w.^2));
end
```

Also, above mentioned function is the piece of code to be converted into python and can any help me in translating this for me?

Comment: @user:5211833 thankyou! for the edit. As you are familiar with MATLAB, could you please explain what the expression ' euc_d=abs((sum(w.*x')+b))/sqrt(sum(w.^2)); ' mean??

Comment: Have you read the [MATLAB help for `fitcsvm`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html)?

Comment: @nekomatic  No!.. but I went through this link https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationsvm.html and ended up with the above doubt. I wanted a clarification on what these properties are called in scikit learn in reference to the SVM attributes mentioned in the link, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html